# grails won't save but have no error

Tags: java, grails, jakarta-ee, grails-domain-class

Hi I have a domain that so simple like the following

```
// page 52 Bankruptcy Questions 
class FamilyLawFinancial{

    Date dateOfTheOrder ;
    boolean isPartyToFamilyLawProperty = false; 
    boolean isCurrentlyInvolvedInFamilyLawProperty = false;
    boolean isBecomeInvolvedInProceedings = false;

    static belongsTo=[person:Person];

    static constraints = {
        dateOfTheOrder(nullable:true);
        isPartyToFamilyLawProperty(nullable:false);
        isCurrentlyInvolvedInFamilyLawProperty(nullable:false);
        isBecomeInvolvedInProceedings(nullable:false);
    }

    String toString(){
        "${id}"
    }
}
```

and here is the controller that save the data:

```
    def save = {
    def person = Person.get(session.curperson.id);
    def obj = FamilyLawFinancial.findByPerson(person);
    if(obj == null){
        obj = new FamilyLawFinancial();
        obj.person = person ; 
    }
    params.dateOfTheOrder = myutil.formatDate(params.dateOfTheOrder);
    obj.properties = params;

    println(obj.hasErrors());
    println(obj.dateOfTheOrder);
    if(obj.hasErrors() && !obj.save(flush:true)){
        println("errors: ${obj.errors}");
        flash.message = "error found";
        println("save familyLawFinancial errors: ${errors}");
    }else{
        flash.message = "saved ";
    }
    redirect(controller:'frontPage', action:'index'); return ;
}
```

The obj.hasErrors() produce false (it means no error) but it wont save into the database. Any idea how to debug this ?

ps: myutil.formatDate() --> for converting the Date String such as 19/11/2010 to Date()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(obj.hasErrors() && !obj.save(flush:true)){
```

The condition after `&&` will not be evaluated if the condition before evaluates to `false`.

As `false && true` evaluates to `false`, evaluating the second condition would be inefficient from the language's point of view.

After all, in this case, `obj.save(..)` never gets called.